# best practices to open more than one PR

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I'm working in a personal project with some new features(well-defined) and I will open PR from each feature to my reviewer.

But my reviewer will only be able to look at my PR once a week, then I will finish more than one feature until it.

I want to know from which branch I create another one after the first PR.

For example(we will only work with master and feature-branches):

I created a branch called feature-one from the master, made 4 commits on it, completed the job and pushed and opened a PR. Now for feature-two I open a new branch ... as long as the reviewer has not yet looked at my first PR, this feature-two branch I create from the master branch or from the feature-one branch that I already did PR has not yet been reviewed?

This will happen in several scenarios where PRs can be intelligent or independent features (like new controllers and layouts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the PR is a request to merge into `master`.

In that case, every feature should be its own individual branch, branching from the latest state of `master`. Just before submitting a finished feature as a PR, pull `master` and rebase that branch onto `master`.

All other workers should behave the same way.

Comment: I'm the only dev on the project, so I'm going to go up to PR and there will be nothing to pull, I just need to continue the work until the reviewer doesn't approve, in which case I would create the new branch from the branch that I opened the PR for? Because if I open the master I will not have the latest changes from the previous PR (not yet approved), am I thinking correctly?

Comment: That's right, but you are the source of the PRs so you still have the older feature branch on your machine, so, not having the stuff in that branch worries you, cherry pick the last commit onto your newer branch. The important thing is to keep the histories of the feature branches separate. — However, personally, I would say, do _not_ cherry pick, since you would then be depending upon something that is not yet approved. You would be going behind the approver's back. Try to write features that are completely independent.

Comment: yes, as the only one to create PR, I will always have the oldest resource branch on your machine, so I will always create other branches from the last one created! It will be the branch of the branch!

Comment: You are correct, it does not make sense to pass a feature continuation onwards without approving the previous one if they are correlated!